# TRIGGER SALESFORCE/APEX

Tags: class, triggers, salesforce, apex

I have to complete a challenge and i have no idea where to starts it.

I created the object "customer", with the fields: name, birth date, age, and account (lookp up to account)

1- Dont allow insert record if the birth date is empty, and shows an error message to the user.
2-dont allow to create a record of customer with age less than 18, and shows an error message to the user.
3-if the field account is empty shoud create automatically an account and insert on the field.
4-when a record is created a new opportunity should be create and the field customer should be filled.

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/354577)